# Unloaded event not fired for same type of UserControl in wpf

Tags: wpf, events

I have 2 Tab controls (UserControl) in my WPF application. Since both this tab controls are created dynamically based on back end data, I have both the tab controls of same class type but different objects (confirmed it by checking the memory address of both, which are different)

I have this strange situation where Unload event is not getting fired when I switch between the tabs (UserControl) of same type. However, the Unload event gets called when I switch from/to tabs of different type.

Am I suppose to handle some other event apart from Unload event?

Please help me with this.. I am stuck :(

Comment: What are you trying to do? According to Microsoft, the `Unloaded` event `Occurs when the element is removed from within an element tree of loaded elements.`

Answer (score 1):

After spending some more time and investigating, I could come to the solution to my question.

The issue was seen because WPF was just changing the DataContext of my UserControl everytime I switch between the Tab controls of same type and since the UsrControl was of same type, even though different object, Unload event was not getting triggered.

The **solution** to this problem is instead of handling **Unload** event, handle **DataContextChanged** event of the UserControl.

Thanks all for the answers !!

Cheers,
Nayan

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to subscribe to the **OnSelectionChanged** event, like so:

XAML:

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl1_OnSelectionChanged">
```

Code-behind:

```
private void TabControl1_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //do whatever
}
```